# Dirname in Nuxt

Tags: node.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am trying to read files in a directory but cannot because __dirname is undefined

nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  router: {
    middleware: ['database']
  },
  build: {
    extend: function (config, __ctx) {
      config.node = {
        fs: "empty",
        module: "empty",
        net: "empty",
      };
    },
  },
}
```

What can be done to determine __dirname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I figured it out, Webpack always sets the *__dirname* to '/'. But probably not on server side.
Maybe this reference will help you resolve your issue: https://codeburst.io/use-webpack-with-dirname-correctly-4cad3b265a92

You didn't say much what you are trying to accomplish, but I will wrote down a solution for one of the most common issues which usually result in people trying to use *__dirname* constant. Maybe it will also help you ;)

Whenever I tried to use *__dirname* in Nuxt, it was because I had to make a workaround for the missing *require.context* functionality in server side process (SSR).
Doing some workarounds with *require* and *__dirname* usually caused even more issues.
The best solution if you are struggling with missing *require.context* in Nuxt server side process is to use [Plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/). They can use *require.context* function and are available both on server side and on client side.

Overall, I think that you should try and find your files with webpack's context functionality and avoid using *__dirname*.

```
const files = require.context('~/', true, /\/your-file-name\/.*\.ts$/)
files.keys().map(key => {
   // This is an example how to access your file's default export.
   // You will probably have to amend it to make any use of it ;)
   const file = files(key).default
})
```